# How to Extract hyperlinks from text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My xml has the following element:

```
<output_citation>C. T. Pan, R. R. Nair, U. Bangert, Q. Ramasse, R. Jalil, R. Zan, C. R. Seabourne, and A. J. Scott. (2012). Nanoscale electron diffraction and plasmon spectroscopy of single- and few-layer boron nitride. <em>Physical Review B</em>, 85(4), 045440.  eScholarID:<a class="escholarid"
        href="http://www.blah.ac.uk/escholar/uk-ac-blah-scw:205189">205189</a> | DOI:<a class="doi" href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.045440">10.1103/PhysRevB.85.045440</a></output_citation>
```

Using XSLT 1.0
I need to extract the two hyperlinks and display them as clickable links.
I have managed to extract the first one using:

```
<xsl:variable name="urlEscholarId" select="output_citation/a/@href"> </xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="labelEscholarId" select="substring-after($urlEscholarId,'scw:')">       </xsl:variable>
 <a>
<xsl:attribute name="href"> 
<xsl:value-of select="$urlEscholarId"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="$labelDoiId"/>
</a>
```

Which gives me:

```
<a href="http://www.blah.ac.uk/escholar/uk-ac-blah-scw:205189">205189</a>
```

I can't seem to extract the second one and also how to output the above text EXCLUDING th eurls?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you show the output you actually expect in this case? It looks like you could just do `<xsl:copy-of select="output_citation/node()" />` in this instance...

Comment: @TimC Perhaps the `class` attribute should no longer be in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Note: These solutions show how to perform the tasks in isolation. This might or might not work well with your existing XSLT stylesheet. If it does not, you'd have to reveal more of the code.

**1 Outputting HTML links**

Perhaps there is no need for `for-each` loops or variables at all (they are in a way working against the functional nature of XSLT, anyway). To find both links simply write a template to match `a` elements, create a new `a` element (or copy the existing one) and copy the `href` attribute and the text content of the original `a` element.

I assume that the `class` attribute should not appear in the output.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <a>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@href|text()"/>
        </a>   
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a href="http://www.blah.ac.uk/escholar/uk-ac-blah-scw:205189">205189</a>
<a href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.045440">10.1103/PhysRevB.85.045440</a>
```

---

**2 Outputting only text content**

> and also how to output the above text EXCLUDING the urls?

That's a different task, but also easily solvable on its own. This outputs all text, save for text nodes that are children of an `a` element.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" /> 

    <xsl:template match="a/text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

> C. T. Pan, R. R. Nair, U. Bangert, Q. Ramasse, R. Jalil, R. Zan, C. R. Seabourne, and A. J. Scott. (2012). Nanoscale electron diffraction and plasmon spectroscopy of single- and few-layer boron nitride. Physical Review B, 85(4), 045440.  eScholarID: | DOI: